# Sending to server via tcp

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Data is not sent to the server although the connection is working properly, if possible, send an example of connecting to the server to send data in one stream.

```
class Server {
  Socket? _socket;
    
  void connectToServer() async {
    try {
      _socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 7890);
      log('connected: ${_socket!.remoteAddress.address}:${_socket!.remotePort}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
    
  void send(temp) {
    _socket?.listen((List<int> event) {
      log(utf8.decode(event));
    });
    _socket?.add(utf8.encode(temp));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the write function.

```
_socket?.write({'tes' : 'test'});
_socket?.writeln('test');
```

Comment: Does not work. Is not coming

Comment: @Extro and how do you know that exactly? What does your server code look like?